# how do I condense this statement?

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
<?php
class Test{
function myFunction(){
   return array('first','second','third'); 
}
}
?>
```

And I can print out the elements of the array:

```
$var=new Test();
$varr=$var->myFunction();
print($varr[1]);
```

Is there a way to condense this statement so I don't have to assign $var->myFunction() to a second variable (in this case $varr)?

Comment: what if you pass the index of the array to `myFunction()` and have it return that

Comment: Questioner wanted to learn about something in OOP, not a basic programming subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not support this very well (as of PHP 5.3) as [Tim Cooper already highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8647386/367456). So you need to think twice if you really need to have this compacted.

You can do things quite dynamically e.g. by return an `ArrayObject` instead of an array:

```
class Test
{
    function myFunction()
    {
        return new ArrayObject(array('first','second','third'), 3); 
    }
}

$var = new Test();
print($var->myFunction()->{1});
```

Which will decorate the array data with some additional methods and ways of accessing. Another way would be for functions w/o parameter to fool the PHP parser and offer a property instead of a function dynamically:

```
class Test
{
    function myFunction()
    {
        return array('first','second','third'); 
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name();
    }
}

$var = new Test();
print($var->myFunction[1]);
```

But I don't know if this is really useful in an application.

So check your motivation why you want to compact the code and then decide on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.4 you'll be able to do:

```
$varr=$var->myFunction()[1];
```

Until then, using [`list`](http://php.net/list) might help out:

```
list(,$varr) = $var->myFunction();
```

Another solution is to modify your method to accept an optional index of the item to return:

```
function myFunction($index = null){
   $arr = array('first','second','third'); 
   return $index == null ? $arr : $arr[$index];
}
```

```
$varr = $var->myFunction(1);
```

Comment: hmmmm. I'm stuck with v. 5.2. It looks like I'll have to wait 'till 5.4 stable comes out...bummer!

Comment: @user522962:  I just added another possible solution to my answer